# Error in aside menu example

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying an example for aside menu. I am getting an error when I am using aside menu in my example.

I wrote the code for that, if I write multiple controllers and I inject `$aside`, I am getting an error `$uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- $aside`, I added the code bellow.

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="asideApp">

<head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.2.0" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/dbtek/angular-aside/master/dist/css/angular-aside.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/dbtek/angular-aside/master/dist/js/angular-aside.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Angular Aside</h1>
        <p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-click="openAside('left', true)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span> Left
            </button>
            <a href="https://github.com/dbtek/angular-aside" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> Download</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg pull-right" ng-click="openAside('right')">
                Menu <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
            </button>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Aside.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">ngAside</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    Look i'm in aside.
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

#### Script.js

```
angular.module('asideApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAside'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $aside) {
        var asideInstance = $scope.openAside = function openAside(position) {
            $aside.open({
                placement: position,
                templateUrl: 'aside.html',
                size: 'lg'
            });
        };
    });
```

My problem is that if I write multiple controllers, htmls and I inject `$aside` in that I am getting the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <-
 $uibModal <- $aside
     http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/unpr?p0=%24uibModalProvider%20%3C-%20%24uibModal%20%3C-%20%24aside
         at angular.js:68
         at angular.js:4255
         at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4402)
         at angular.js:4260
         at getService (angular.js:4402)
         at Object.invoke (angular.js:4434)
         at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular.js:4296)
         at Object.invoke (angular.js:4443)
         at angular.js:4261
         at getService (angular.js:4402)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: guys do you have examples for side menu,if i open the menu open side menu and click on the on of the item in side menu it will go to that page?If u Please send me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your current  angular version is not supporting **`ngAside`** directive.Please change your version to stable version.I faced same issue before.